# print lines between start and end using sed

Tags: sed

I need to print the lines between two delimiters. For example, given the input

```
fluff1
fluff2
BEGIN
good3
good4
END
fluff5
fluff6
BEGIN
good7
good8
END
more fluff
```

I want the output to be

```
good3
good4
good7
good8
```

I know how to do it with `awk`, but hoping to find a shorter solution with `sed`.

What I would like it to be is the following, but that is of course invalid syntax:

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/+1,/END/-1p'
```

Comment: Can you please post your solution in `awk`?

Comment: Something on line lines of `/BEGIN/ { found=1; } found {print} /END/ { found = 0; }`. Hmm, actually its not very long :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/{/^BEGIN$/d;/^END$/d;p;}' input
```

Comment: I was hoping it won't be some long winded thing with pattern and hold spaces and indeed it is not. I would have liked not to have to repeat the delimiters because in my case they are much longer but this will do. Thank you!

Comment: This can be shortened to `sed -n -e '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/{//!p}' input`

Comment: @potong But noone understands that.

Comment: @potong, your change doesnt work on OSX but the post one does.

Comment: Why do you need the `-e` switch?

Comment: @mbigras It is not necessary; I am just used to it.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `sed` 3.95 or above, you can do:

```
sed '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/!d;//d'
```

With other `sed`s, you may have to write it:

```
sed '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/!d;//d;/^BEGIN$/d'
```

Or even

```
sed '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/!d;/^END$/d;/^BEGIN$/d'
```

like with busybox `sed`.

See also the [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24)

Comment: `sed '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/!d;//d'` results in no output (GNU sed-Version 4.2.1)

Comment: I've just verified that it works with all of 3.95, 4.0, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2. Prior to that (3.02.80 and before (1999)), it outputs "BEGIN" just like the traditional Unix seds.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I had not replaced the whole line but just my sed command against yours. The `-n` prevented the output... I had checked the file with `od` (no CRs). But the most obvious...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to repeat the delimiters you could use Perl:

```
perl -ne '/BEGIN/ && do {$a=1; next}; $a=0 if /END/; print if $a' input
```

You could also modify HaukeLaging's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78479/22222) to use variables:

```
b="BEGIN"; e="END"; sed -n -e "/^$b$/,/^$e$/{/^$b$/d;/^$e$/d;p}" input
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to include the delimiters you could do `sed -ne "/BEGIN/,/END/{p;}" $INPUT`

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, that's not the aim of this question.